# iGraph install error with Python Anywhere

Tags: igraph, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to run a web app (built with flask-wtforms and using iGraph) on Pythonanywhere. As igraph isn't part of the already inculded modules, I try and install it using the bash console, as such:

> pip install --user python-igraph

How ever, what I get is:

> Could not download and compile the C core of igraph.

It usually means (according to other people having the same issue on Stackoverflow) that I need to first install:

> sudo apt-get install -y libigraph0-dev

Except, apt-get isn't available on Pythonanywhere, as far as I know.

Is there any workaround to install the iGraph module for Python 2.7 on Pythonanywhere?

Comment: It is probably best if you send them an email, especially because their help page says so ("If your package installation fails with an error that looks like it might have been trying to compile something, you'll need to contact us to get us to install it for you. Use the "send feedback" button." - see https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules). Also, you should not need `libigraph0-dev` - if the C core is not available, the setup script tries to download and compile it, so most likely something goes wrong during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

python-igraph installed perfectly fine in my account. My guess is that you're facing a different issue to a missing library. Perhaps a network error or something like that.